# How to add Dynamic application security testing for mono repo?

Tags: security, sast

If GIT repo is mono repo then how to add dast job for all projects in mono repo and can we add two dast jobs for different environments?

Tried to add different dast jobs but getting yaml error like dast job config needs trigger and script. and For Mono repo project have created different scanner and site profile for different projects but pipeline is only taking first project dast job for scan.